# Vistas mvc con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estoy iniciando un nuevo proyecto MVC con Entity Framwork y necesito guardar información en 3 tablas diferentes, para ello he creado un procedimiento almacenado.
Lo que quiero hacer es crear un formulario a partir de ese procedimiento.

¿Qué puedo hacer para crear el formulario? ¿ me podrían ayudar con un ejemplo ?

Comment: si recien andas iniciando, este workshop que hice te será de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY //contiene lo básico, un proyecto de 3 capas :D

Comment: Pregunta: Si vas a utilizar EF, necesitas realmente crear ese SP?

Comment: Lo cree por que necesito guarda info en 3 tablas (usuarios, info y comentarios) la tabla de usuarios genera un Id, que es necesario insertar en las otras 2 tablas, el procedimieto que genere inserta en la tabla usuarios, y devuelve el id que se genera para insertarlo en las otras 2.
La otra  manera en que lo hice, fue creando una clase para unir los 3 modelos y crear una vista, y funciona pero tengo que insertar manualmente los id. 
Soy nuevo en esto de la programación. @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: gracias @fredyfx

Comment: @DevCastillo de nada hermano, estamos para servir :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetResultsForCampaign]  
@ClientId int   
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT AgeGroup, Gender, Payout
FROM IntegrationResult
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
END
```

Creamos una clase que va así:

```
public class ResultForCampaign
{
    public string AgeGroup { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public decimal Payout { get; set; }
}
```

Y llamamos al procedimiento almacenado haciendo lo siguiente:

```
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
        var clientIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@ClientId", 4);

        var result = context.Database
            .SqlQuery<ResultForCampaign>("GetResultsForCampaign @ClientId", clientIdParameter)
            .ToList();
}
```